# Passing Data betwen Two Fragments

Tags: android

i have a main activity and alot with fragments in it .. now i want to pass data between fragment to another fragment 
Help me with this ...

try to use intent but its never did what i want and errors occures

this is my source fragment :

```
public class SubCategoryDetail extends Fragment {
View view;
SubCategory subCategory;

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

RecyclerView includedView, relatedView, popularView;

TextView titlePricing, titleIncluded, pricing1, pricing2;

Spinner spinner;


    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategory_detail, container, false);

    bindViews();
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).visibility(false, false, false);
    return view;
}

private void bindViews() {
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        subCategory = (SubCategory) bundle.getSerializable("data");
    }

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);


    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener());





    getDetails();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getDetails();
        }
    });


}




    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(subCategory.getImage()).into(bannerTop);
    title.setText(subCategory.getName());
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(subCategory.getImages(), getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    description.setText(subCategory.getDescription());

    IncludedAdapter includedAdapter = new IncludedAdapter(subCategory.getInclude(), getActivity());
    includedView.setAdapter(includedAdapter);




    PopularAdapter popularAdapter = new PopularAdapter(subCategory.getPopular(), getActivity());
    popularView.setAdapter(popularAdapter);

    TypefaceHelper.typeface(title, MyApplication.getBold());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(description, MyApplication.getLight());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(allProvider, MyApplication.getRegular());

    TypefaceHelper.typeface(titleIncluded, MyApplication.getRegular());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(titlePricing, MyApplication.getRegular());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(pricing1, MyApplication.getLight());
    TypefaceHelper.typeface(pricing2, MyApplication.getLight());


}


private void disableViews(Boolean what) {
    for (int i = 0; i < swipeRefreshLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = swipeRefreshLayout.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(what);
    }
}


public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularAdapter.Holder> {
    private List<Category> list;
    private Context context;

    public PopularAdapter(List<Category> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PopularAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new PopularAdapter.Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popular_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PopularAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {

        final Category category = list.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(category.getImage())

                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.home)
                        .error(R.drawable.home)
                        .centerCrop())

                .into(holder.icon);
        holder.name.setText(category.getName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("data", category);
                bundle.putString("from", "one");
                bundle.putString("name", category.getName());
                SubCategoryFragment fragment = new SubCategoryFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ((HomeActivity) context).changeFragment(fragment, "Sub Category");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView icon;
        TextView name;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_item);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);

            TypefaceHelper.typeface(name, MyApplication.getLight());

        }
    }
}
```

Mainly this is what i want to pass !!

```
    public class ItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    //get strings of first item
    String firstItem = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(pos == 0) {
            String ex = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            String ex2 = ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);

        }
        else if(pos == 1) {
            String ex = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            String ex2 = ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ex2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else if(pos == 2) {
            String ex = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            String ex2 = ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ex2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else if(pos == 3) {
            String ex = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            String ex2 = ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ex2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else if(pos == 4) {
            String ex = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            String ex2 = ex.substring(ex.lastIndexOf("+") + 1);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ex2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg) {

    }

}
}
```

please tell me the way that i can pass this data to a textview in the second fragment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the data to a fragment say myFragment then see snippet below

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message",msg); //here msg is value you want to pass
myFragment fragment=new myFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);`
```

now to access this in myFragment class using code (generally declared in oncreate() of fragment class):

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
if(bundle!=null){
 Textiew textView.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getString("message")));
}
```